Boolean modifier with screw on rounded surface
complete newbie here.
I created a non-flat surface and a screw. I want to get a screw thread in the heart but when using the boolean tool the final result looks unfinished. I would prefer for the outside edges to be a complete circle while still maintaining the screw thread.
I'm sure I'm missing something. How would you experts go about this?
For clarity's sake: I literally just used the boolean modifier on the heart, selected the screw as the object which to use the modifier with and applied.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
|



Hi. I think the only way to improve that is by increasing the complexity of the mesh for the heart by a considerable amount..

I think you need to take the bigger radius of the screw, make it into a cylinder, bevel that cylinder, and use its beveled tip to boolean cut again in order to chamfer ("bevel") the opening in the heart. Otherwise you won't get a perfect circle, because a cross-section of a screw isn't a perfect circle.
